# Expression for "running/getting out of somewhere really fast"

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word or expression to mean 
 **running out of somewhere very fast** because of being terrified of something, or to avoid meeting someone.

Comment: "Beat a retreat"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a handy single word: **flee**. You may *flee* a place or a person or a threat.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are looking also for an 'expression', I would suggest:

> **like a bat out of hell**
>   if you go somewhere like a bat out of hell, you go very fast *He ran out of the building like a bat out of hell*.

(Ref. Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2006.)

Comment: This was going to be my answer! First thing that popped to mind, and while the other answers are good this one is the best I think. +1! (Haha, I also just realized it's a bit of a coincidence that the question was posted by 'Batman' ;))

Comment: @WendiKidd, I suspect the idiom on `BAT` really struck Carlo_R's mind seeing the OP's name. :P

Comment: Are you a meatloaf fan by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

In Northern English (e.g. Manchester, Liverpool), this phrase is quite common

> When those guys showed up, **we legged it**.

In US informal English there's also "skedaddle":

> When those guys showed up, we **skedaddled outta** there!

Perhaps more commonly you can always use an intensifier to impress upon the listener that you got out of there quickly:

> When those guys showed up, we **got the hell** outta there!

Comment: *Legging it* is not only used in the north.

Comment: @Tristan: +1, but it is more common on the North.

Answer (score 5):

It always sounds a bit "slangy" to me, but a nice word for OP's context is...

> [skedaddle](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=skedaddle&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=QAoYUaW2EsiY0QW4jIGgCg&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k&fp=8ec4270eec57e3fe&biw=1322&bih=885) *- to depart quickly or hurriedly; run away*.

...another one I like (esp. US usage, also somewhat informal, as are most apart from *flee*) is...

> [high-tail it out of here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22high-tail%20it%20out%20of%20here%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) deriving from the raised [tails of fleeing animals (as deer or rabbits)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/high-tail+it).

Similar terms include *scarper, leg it, beat it, clear off*.

Comment: FF, are they not all from American English?

Comment: @Tristan: I hadn't realised until checking just now that *skedaddle* began as US military slang in the mid 1800s. Apparently *beat it* is also US (early C20), but *scarper* certainly seems to be of British origin, and I'm inclined to think *leg it* and *clear off* are too. Incidentally, in my link above, dictionary.com says of *hightail it* that this is an Americanism, 1885–90, but OED's first citation is significantly later, at 1925.

Comment: @FF: You're right about *scarper*. I overlooked that. I didn't know about the origin of *clear off*. I've hardly heard anyone use it. Regarding *leg it*, I commented about that under Matt's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the verb ***bolt***. NOAD defines it like this:

[image: NOAD bolt]

As a side note, in recent years, this option has been a very handy word for [sports headlines](http://www.capitalfm.co.ke/sports/2013/02/10/usain-bolts-to-solid-400m-win/).

Comment: Reminds me of 
[Usain Bolt](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt).Perhaps this word is made for him ;)

Answer (score 1):

(American) slang includes **bail**, **scram**, and **vamoose**. 
Variations on **get the hell** outta there include [get out of Dodge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_out_of_Dodge) and [get the hell out of Dodge](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19990104). 
**Rats leaving a sinking ship** is maybe not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

"Skip out" can be used in the said contexts as in

> John was arrested July 22 after he *skipped out* on a $300 bill earlier at a local bar and ran away.

[Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/skip-out) defines it as a phrasal verb which means

> to leave a place quickly, usually because you do not want to be noticed or want to avoid paying money

Comment: Along with *slip out*, and expressions like *skip bail*, I think the (relatively uncommon, imho) *skip out* is normally only used in contexts where you're *avoiding onerous responsibilities* (such having to speak to someone who bores you, or to pay for something). It doesn't sound like something you'd say if you were running away terrified of something.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that it may not be used in the "running away terrified" scenarios but OP did ask for "avoid meeting someone" scenario where it could still be used as that *avoidance* could be due to a multiplicity of reasons.

Answer (score -1):

There's the expression *run off*, as in:

> "Run off to somewhere else!"